# how to store the time in android database

Tags: android, database, datetime

In my application, the time will be store for certain duration and it will store in database,any one can help me to solve problem.

Answer (score 0):

To Store Time In Database I hope this code help you.

```
   SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "HH:mm:ss");
   Date date = new Date();
```

And use this when storing in database.

```
simpleDateFormat.format(date).toString()
```